How do I force Windows to open programs on the active desktop?
I use multiple desktops in Windows a lot.
The problem I have is that when I open a program, Windows remembers that another program of the same type is open on desktop 2, and it forces the new window to open on that desktop.
For example, if I have an excel file open on Desktop 2, but I'm currently working on desktop 3, if I try to open another excel file, it opens it on Desktop 2.
This is hyper frustrating, as I want specific windows open on specific desktops, but I open a lot of other programs all day long, and they just end up on whatever damn desktop they feel like it.
How do I force it such that if I'm on desktop 3, and I open a new excel file, it opens on Desktop 3 instead of whatever desktop it feels like?

This question belongs on [su], as it is a general software/operating system question. SO is strictly for questions related to programming. We make an exception and allow Excel formulas here, because they can be quite complex, and Excel VBA questions, but not general Excel use questions. We also allow operating system questions when they are related to the code or API for that OS, but not for its general usage.  For more information about what is appropriate to ask here, see the [help].
